# MQ manager ends automatically

Tags: ibm-mq

I just installed IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer Version: 7.5.0.0.  I created a Queue Manager 'TestQ' and right click and started the queue manager.  It started perfectly and after couple of seconds it ended automatically.

When I start the same from command line it started as usual and after couple of seconds it ends automatically.

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\MQSI\9.0.0.0>strmqm TestQ
WebSphere MQ queue manager 'TestQ' starting.
The queue manager is associated with installation 'Installation1'.
43 log records accessed on queue manager 'TestQ' during the log replay phase.
Log replay for queue manager 'TestQ' complete.
Transaction manager state recovered for queue manager 'TestQ'.
WebSphere MQ queue manager 'TestQ' started using V7.5.0.0.
```

Is there any problem?

Error output while starting the service is as below (I changed the name of the queue manager to T24MQ)

```
----- amqxfdcp.c : 906 --------------------------------------------------------
4/26/2018 18:31:47 - Process(12296.13) User(134920) Program(amqzmuc0.exe)
                      Host(LT077609) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.0)
AMQ6184: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred on queue manager T24QM.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 12296.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been
resolved.
```

Some additional error details

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                             |
| WebSphere MQ First Failure Symptom Report                                   |
| =========================================                                   |
|                                                                             |
| Date/Time         :- Thu April 26 2018 23:33:28 India Standard Time         |
| UTC Time          :- 1524765808.996000                                      |
| UTC Time Offset   :- 330 ((UNKNOWN))                                        |
| Host Name         :- LT077609                                               |
| Operating System  :- Windows Ver 6.2 (5) Enterprise x64 Edition, Build 9200 |
| PIDS              :- 5724H7220                                              |
| LVLS              :- 7.5.0.0                                                |
| Product Long Name :- WebSphere MQ for Windows                               |
| Vendor            :- IBM                                                    |
| Installation Path :- C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ                |
| Installation Name :- Installation1    (1)                                   |
| Probe Id          :- ZF095010                                               |
| Application Name  :- MQM                                                    |
| Component         :- zfuCacheAuthQueue                                      |
| SCCS Info         :- F:\build\p000_P\src\cmd\oam\amqzfuma.c,                |
| Line Number       :- 1209                                                   |
| Build Date        :- Jun  4 2012                                            |
| Build Level       :- p000-L120604                                           |
| Build Type        :- IKAP - (Production)                                    |
| UserID            :- 134920                                                 |
| Process Name      :- C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\amqzfu     |
|                      ma.exe                                                 |
| Addressing mode   :- 32-bit                                                 |
| Process           :- 00012432                                               |
| Thread            :- 00000001                                               |
| QueueManager      :- T24QM                                                  |
| UserApp           :- FALSE                                                  |
| ConnId(2) QM      :- 4                                                      |
| Last HQC          :- 2.5.5-5978432                                          |
| Last HSHMEMB      :- 2.2.2-8112                                             |
| Major Errorcode   :- MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED                                    |
| Minor Errorcode   :- OK                                                     |
| Probe Type        :- INCORROUT                                              |
| Probe Severity    :- 4                                                      |
| Probe Description :- AMQ6125: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred.  |
| FDCSequenceNumber :- 0                                                      |
|                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You say "after a couple of seconds it ends automatically" do you see any messages in either the MQ install location under `errors\AMQERR01.LOG` or `errors\*.FDC` or `qmgrs\TestQ\errors\AMQERR01.LOG` that corrispond to the time of when the queue manager stops?  If you could edit and add that to your question it would be helpful in understanding why this may be happening.

Comment: Along with that info from the `AMQERR01.LOG` there should be a file with a name like `AMQ12296.0.FDC`, at the start of that file there is a block of lines that start with either `+` or `|`, can you paste that into the question as well.

Comment: It looks like a permission issue?

Comment: Open a CMD prompt on the server and change to the directory with the FDC files and run `ffstsummary` and paste the output that has time stamps around the same time.   Looks like the user you have associated with the mq install may not be in the correct group.   Do you have  local mqm group and is it a member?

Comment: Is user '134920' in the local mqm group? If not, add it and retry. If it is, try strmqm -c, and if that doesnt help, can you start the qmgr under a different id (e.g. your logged on id if elevated or in local mqm group try strmqm -si)

Answer (score 1):

Several problems for a new user to MQ:

> I just installed IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer Version: 7.5.0.0.

Why?  It goes out of support in 5 days!!  You should have installed IBM MQ V8 or IBM MQ V9.

Secondly, do you mean you installed MQ which contains MQ Explorer?  Because just installing MQ Explorer (aka SupportPac MS0T) does not contain MQ server components to create a queue manager.

Third, did you already have a version of MQ installed then install MQ Explorer from a DIFFERENT release of MQ?  Bad idea.  Very bad idea.

> I created a Queue Manager 'TestQ'

IBM MQ Best Practices Standard is for queue manager names and MQ object names to be in UPPERCASE.  You are asking for a world of pain using mixed-case.

Secondly, 'TestQ' sounds like a queue name and not a queue manager name.

Third, it is far, far better to delete queue manager 'TestQ' and create it called 'TESTQM'.